# Missing Symbology Categories after performing join using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, layers, symbology, feature-layer

I am trying to join a table to a feature class in , and use the joined fields to create custom symobology based on the joined fields as the *picture 1 below*  for Arcmap using ArcObjects. I am successfully joining the tables, and I can see the new fields in the layer when I open it's attribute table, however once successfully joined, and the code runs to specify the rederer I check the symbology and the entire category criteria gets hidden as *picture 2*. What could be causing this ? It is very strange, when I remove the code where the layer and table get joined, the symbology becomes correct using the 3 values I specified and it doesn't disappear.

[image: Picture 1]
[[image: Picture 2[2]]

Here my code

```
   protected override void OnClick()
    {

    // code that gets all the proper objects
    //..
       JoinTables(table,ftrClass,ftrLayer);
       var geoLayer=(IGeoFeatureLayer)ftrLayer;
       CreateRenderer(geoLayer);

    }


      // method to join table and ftr class layer
     public void JoinTables(  IStandaloneTable pStTable,IFeatureLayer ftrLayer, IFeatureClass ftrClass){
       var pTabCollection = (IStandaloneTableCollection)arcMapApp.Document.FocusMap;
        if (pTabCollection.StandaloneTableCount == 0) {
          return;
        }
        var pDispTable2 = (IDisplayTable)pStTable;
        var pTTable = pDispTable2.DisplayTable;
        IMemoryRelationshipClassFactory pMemRelFact;
        IRelationshipClass pRelClass;
        pMemRelFact = new MemoryRelationshipClassFactoryClass();
        pRelClass = pMemRelFact.Open("JoinedLayerAndTable", (IObjectClass)pTTable, "CL_ID",
          (IObjectClass)ftrClass, "ID", "forward", "backward", esriRelCardinality.esriRelCardinalityOneToMany);
        var dispRC = (IDisplayRelationshipClass)ftrLAyer;
        dispRC.DisplayRelationshipClass(pRelClass, esriJoinType.esriLeftOuterJoin); 
  }




   public void CreateRenderer( IGeoFeatureLayer ftrLAyer){

        IUniqueValueRenderer renderer = new UniqueValueRendererClass();

        renderer.FieldCount = 3;
        renderer.Field[0] = "CATEGORY_NAME";
        renderer.Field[1] = "TYPE_NAME";
        renderer.Field[2] = "UUID";
        renderer.FieldDelimiter = "|";
        renderer.ColorScheme = "Custom";
        renderer.FieldType[0] = true;
        renderer.FieldType[1] = true;
        renderer.FieldType[2] = true;

        ILineSymbol smb = new SimpleLineSymbolClass();
        smb.Width = 2;
        IRgbColor clr = new RgbColorClass();
        clr.Red = 255;
        clr.Green = 0;
        clr.Blue = 0;
        smb.Color = clr;

        renderer.AddValue("XX1|INSUR|DWA", "www", (ISymbol)smb);
        pGeoFeatureLayer.Renderer = (IFeatureRenderer)renderer;
        var pUID = new UIDClass();
        pUID.Value = "{683C994E-A17B-11D1-8816-080009EC732A}";
        pGeoFeatureLayer.RendererPropertyPageClassID = pUID;
        arcMapApp.Document.UpdateContents();
        arcMapApp.Document.ActivatedView.Refresh();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention that you are trying to join your table to the feature class, but your code below is doing the opposite.

```
pRelClass = pMemRelFact.Open("JoinedLayerAndTable", (IObjectClass)pTTable, "CL_ID", (IObjectClass)ftrClass, "ID", "forward", "backward", esriRelCardinality.esriRelCardinalityOneToMany);
```

Try the following:

```
public void JoinTables(IStandaloneTable pStTable, IFeatureLayer ftrLayer) {

    var ftLayerDispTable = (IDisplayTable)ftrLayer;
    var ftrDisplayTable = ftLayerDispTable.DisplayTable;

    var pDispTable2 = (IDisplayTable)pStTable;
    var pTTable = pDispTable2.DisplayTable;

    IMemoryRelationshipClassFactory pMemRelFact = new MemoryRelationshipClassFactoryClass();

    var pRelClass = pMemRelFact.Open("JoinedLayerAndTable", (IObjectClass) ftrDisplayTable, "ID",
        (IObjectClass) pTTable, "CL_ID", "forward", "backward", esriRelCardinality.esriRelCardinalityOneToOne);

    var dispRc = (IDisplayRelationshipClass)ftrLayer;
    dispRc.DisplayRelationshipClass(pRelClass, esriJoinType.esriLeftOuterJoin);
}
```

You also need to use the following when setting the property page `pUid.Value = "esriCartoUI.CombiUniqueValuePropertyPage"`; then you need to call **`ActiveView.ContentsChanged()`**; not `UpdateContents()`

**Edit**: Another thing to note is when using fields from the Joined table in your renderer you need to specify the fully qualified field name in the join table.

Comment: You also need to use the following when setting the property page
pUid.Value = "esriCartoUI.CombiUniqueValuePropertyPage";  then you need to call ActiveView.ContentsChanged(); not UpdateContents()